# How to design http request service? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, httprequest, httpclient

I want to ask for what anyone thinks will be the best implementation for what I want to achieve.

I want to get data from an HTTP request when component initialized and process the data at the same time. The data will come from service that will implement the `HttpClient.get()` request.

Component:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHandleService} from '../services/http-handle.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-http-displayer',
    templateUrl: './http-displayer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./http-displayer.component.css']
})
export class HttpDisplayerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    public data: any = [];

    constructor(private httpHandleService: HttpHandleService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.httpHandleService.getData().subscribe((recivedData) => this.data = recivedData); // get the data 
        doSomthing(this.data); // want to process the data here, but still data is empty array
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        doSomething(this.data);  // want to process the data here, but still, data is an empty array
        // What I was thinking is that by the time this lifecycle hook will be activated this.data will be assigned with the received data.
    }
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpHandleService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can process received data inside your subscribe block.

Comment: Please read up on async JavaScript generally and observables specifically - if you want to use the value in your components, you have to deal with the fact that it won't be available immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Observables are *asynchronous*.

```
this.httpHandleService.getData().subscribe((receivedData) => { 
  this.data = receivedData;
  this.doSomething(this.data); // accessed here
});
```

There are many, many guides on how what an observable is and how it works. Angular has a few: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library